# Circle packing periphery detection on an image

Tags: matlab

I have an image as following

[Circle packing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt4TC.png)

I have created a matlab code that would detect the pixels on the circumference and create a integer mask so I can import it in a C++ code. Here is a snippet of main algo. (I use imread and store the image in a N X N array

```
    for i=1:nx
    for j=1:ny
             if (wholeGeom(j,i) == 255)
                B(j,i) = 1;
             elseif ((wholeGeom(j,i) == 0)&& ...
                     ((i==1||i==nx) && j>1 && j<nx)&& ...
                     (wholeGeom(j+1,i)==255 || ...
                      wholeGeom(j-1,i)==255) )
                    B(j,i) = 2;
             elseif ((wholeGeom(j,i) == 0)&& ...
                     ((j==1||j==nx) && i>1 && i<nx)&& ...
                     (wholeGeom(j,i+1)==255 || ...
                      wholeGeom(j,i-1)==255) )
                    B(j,i) = 2;   
             elseif ((wholeGeom(j,i) == 0)&& ...
                     (i>1 && j>1 && i<nx && j<nx)&& ...
                     (wholeGeom(j+1,i)==255 || ...
                     wholeGeom(j-1,i)==255 ||...
                     wholeGeom(j,i+1)==255 ||...
                     wholeGeom(j,i-1)==255) )
             else
                   B(j,i) = 0;
```

This works well for me.  My output is as follows

[BounceBack Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUlKf.jpg)

I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, especially on matlab.... Any recommendations would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, morphological operations are your friend. [Morphological operations](https://mathworks.com/help/images/morphological-dilation-and-erosion.html) are a very fast tool to work on binary images. You can use [`imdilate`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) to ["dilate"](https://mathworks.com/help/images/dilating-an-image.html) an image, i.e. "thicken" all objects in the image.

```
% Load image
wholeGeom = rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt4TC.png'));

% Threshold to make image binary
wholeGeom = wholeGeom > 128;

% Dilate image, i.e. add 1 pixel to each side of an object
borders = imdilate(wholeGeom, [0,1,0;1,1,1;0,1,0]);

% Set borders to 2 and everything inside object to 1
result = 2*borders - wholeGeom;
```

Result (zoomed in to make border more visible):

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

A more authentic approach to finding any form of parametric shapes is using Hough Transforms which uses a voting mechanism to find any type of parametric shape in an image. In this case you could use :

```
%imfindcircles internally uses Hough Transforms
centers = imfindcircles(img,radius)  
[centers,radii] = imfindcircles(img,radiusRange)
```